# Terminating Android Timer if user doesn't use the App(Prevent running in the background)

Tags: java, android, concurrency, android-animation

I have a `Timer` in my App that infinitely runs an `Animation`. like this:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Running Animation Code
            }
        });
    }
}, 1000, 1000);
```

Now I realized that this code runs even if user click `Back Button` of android. if fact it runs in the background and it seems uses a lot of memory.

I need this code run `ONLY if user in the app`. In fact when user click on `Back Button`, this `Timer` goes to end and if user clicks on `Home Button`, after a while that user doesn't use the App, terminates this `Timer`.

What I need is to prevent using memory. Because i realized if this codes runs a while, App freezes! I need a normal behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Activity` is the last element in the `BackStack`, then it will be put in the background as if you pressed the *Home* button.

As such, the `onPause()` method is triggered.

You can thus cancel your animation there.

```
@Override protected void onPause() {
    this.timer.cancel();
}
```

You should as well start your animation in the `onResume()` method.
Note that `onResume()` is also called right after `onCreate()`; so it's even suitable to start the animation from a cold app start.

```
@Override protected void onResume() {
    this.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(...);
}
```

`onPause()` will be also called if you start another Application from your app (e.g: a Ringtone Picker). In the same way, when you head back to your app, `onResume()` will be triggered.

---

There is no need to add the same line of code in `onBackPressed()`.

Also, what's the point in stopping the animation in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`?

Do it in `onPause()` already. When your are app goes into the background, the animation will already be canceled and **won't be using as much memory**.

Don't know why I see such complicated answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, in `onBackPressed()` or `onDestroy()`, whatever suits you.

```
if (t != null) {
   t.cancel();
}
```

If you need, you can start timer in `onResume()` and cancel it in `onStop()`, it entirely depend on you requirement.

> If a caller wants to terminate a timer's task execution thread
>   rapidly, the caller should invoke the timer's cancel method. - [Android Timer documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

You should also see [purge](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#purge()) and 
[How to stop the Timer in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993765/how-to-stop-the-timer-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This might not be the 100% best way to do this and it might be considered bad practice by some.

I have used the below code in a production app and it works. I have however edited it (removed app specific references and code) into a basic sample that should give you a very good start.

The static `mIsAppVisible` variable can be called anywhere (via your `App` class) in your app to check if code should run based on the condition that the app needs to be in focus/visible.

You can also check `mIsAppInBackground` in your activities that extend `ParentActivity` to see if the app is actually interactive, etc.

---

```
public class App extends Application {
    public static boolean mIsAppVisible = false;


    ...
}
```

---

Create a "Parent" activity class, that all your other activities extend.

```
public class ParentActivity extends Activity {
    public static boolean mIsBackPressed = false;
    public static boolean mIsAppInBackground = false;
    private static boolean mIsWindowFocused = false;
    public boolean mFailed = false;
    private boolean mWasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        applicationWillEnterForeground();

        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        applicationDidEnterBackground();
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();

        // If something calls "finish()" it needs to behave similarly to
        // pressing the back button to "close" an activity. 
        mIsBackPressed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        mIsWindowFocused = hasFocus;

        if (mIsBackPressed && !hasFocus) {
            mIsBackPressed = false;
            mIsWindowFocused = true;
        }

        if (!mIsWindowFocused && mFailed)
            applicationDidEnterBackground();

        if (isScreenOn() && App.mIsAppVisible && hasFocus) {
            // App is back in focus. Do something here...

            // this can occur when the notification shade is
            // pulled down and hidden again, for example.
        }

        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (!mWasScreenOn && mIsWindowFocused)
            onWindowFocusChanged(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // this is for any "sub" activities that you might have
        if (!(this instanceof MainActivity))
            mIsBackPressed = true;

        if (isTaskRoot()) {
            // If we are "closing" the app
            App.mIsAppVisible = false;
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private void applicationWillEnterForeground() {
        if (mIsAppInBackground) {
            mIsAppInBackground = false;
            App.mIsAppVisible = true;

            // App is back in foreground. Do something here...

            // this happens when the app was backgrounded and is
            // now returning
        } else
            mFailed = false;
    }

    private void applicationDidEnterBackground() {
        if (!mIsWindowFocused || !isScreenOn()) {
            mIsAppInBackground = true;
            App.mIsAppVisible = false;

            mFailed = false;

            // App is not in focus. Do something here...
        } else if (!mFailed)
            mFailed = true;
    }

    private boolean isScreenOn() {
        boolean screenState = false;
        try {
            PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);

            screenState = powerManager.isInteractive();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "isScreenOn", e);
        }

        mWasScreenOn = screenState;

        return screenState;
    }
}
```

---

For your use you might want to create a method in your activity (code snippet assumes `MainActivity`) that handles the animation to call the `t.cancel();` method that [penguin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46913774/1878863) suggested. You could then in the `ParentActivity.applicationDidEnterBackground()` method add the following:

```
if (this instanceof MainActivity) {
    ((MainActivity) this).cancelTimer();
}
```

Or you could add the timer to the `ParentActivity` class and then not need the `instanceof` check or the extra method.